# Training Tensorflow BERT finetuning on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I'm running a BERT finetuning using the official script [run_pretraining.py](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_pretraining.py)

This makes use of a `TPUEstimator`

```
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
      use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu,
      model_fn=model_fn,
      config=run_config,
      train_batch_size=FLAGS.train_batch_size,
      eval_batch_size=FLAGS.eval_batch_size)
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps)
```

where the model_fn creates

```
model = modeling.BertModel(
        config=bert_config,
        is_training=is_training,
        input_ids=input_ids,
        input_mask=input_mask,
        token_type_ids=segment_ids,
        use_one_hot_embeddings=use_one_hot_embeddings)
```

with the optimizer `TPUEstimatorSpec`:

```
train_op = optimization.create_optimizer(
          total_loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu)

      output_spec = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimatorSpec(
          mode=mode,
          loss=total_loss,
          train_op=train_op,
          scaffold_fn=scaffold_fn)
```

According to the docs, the `TPUEstimator` should be backed by GPU as fallback of the TPU.

In the script there is any other setup of Tensorflow `session`.
What happens running the script within a docker container with `docker run --runtime=nvidia`, the training starts in CPU:

```
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   47C    P8     7W / 200W |    593MiB /  8111MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

To be sure that we had the GPU device visible I have added `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"`, and started a session:

```
def load_tensorflow_shared_session(self):
        """ Load a Tensorflow/Keras shared session """

        N_CPU = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

        # OMP_NUM_THREADS controls MKL's intra-op parallelization
        # Default to available physical cores
        os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = str( max(1, N_CPU) )

        # LP: set Tensorflow logging level
        MXM_DIST = os.getenv('MXM_DIST', 'prod')
        if MXM_DIST == 'prod':
            tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
        else:
            tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.DEBUG)

        # LP: create a config by gpu cpu backend
        config = tf.ConfigProto(
                device_count={ 'GPU' : 1, 'CPU': N_CPU },
                intra_op_parallelism_threads = 0,
                inter_op_parallelism_threads = N_CPU,
                allow_soft_placement=True
            )
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.6

        # LP: create session by config
        self.tf_session = tf.Session(config=config)

        return self.tf_session
```

therefore wrapping everything in it:

```
train_input_fn = input_fn_builder(
        input_files=input_files,
        max_seq_length=FLAGS.max_seq_length,
        max_predictions_per_seq=FLAGS.max_predictions_per_seq,
        is_training=True)
with session.as_default():
    with session.graph.as_default():
      estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=FLAGS.num_train_steps)
```

I can see `GPU:0` in the device list, but processing occurs on the GPU anyways:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                           
15225 root      20   0 37.956g 0.017t 271720 S 951.8 28.5 904:59.30 run_pretraining
```

Comment: One thing to confirm here: does your TF installation work with GPU using other scripts

Comment: @y.selivonchyk yes, it works. When I wrap in `session.as_default():` loaded with `load_tensorflow_shared_session` I have a `GPU:0` device within the session, and I can see GPU processing with `nvidia-smi`. But not with this `Estimator` code for some reason.